# count the number of record by $match before $group java mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have used aggregation for fetching records from MongoDB. I need to count the number of records return by $match before I do the groupBy (MongoDB) in java. Any help will be appreciated.

```
             List countries =col2.distinct("country");
             for(int i=0;i<countries.size();i++){
                String country1= (String) countries.get(i);
                List<DBObject> pipeline = new ArrayList<DBObject>(Arrays.asList( 
                    new BasicDBObject("$match",new BasicDBObject("country", country1)),
                    new BasicDBObject("$group", 
                        new BasicDBObject("_id","$job_id" )
                          .append("count", new BasicDBObject("$sum",1)
                    ))));
                 AggregationOutput output = col2.aggregate(pipeline);}
```

This is a sample data:
[image]

Comment: You can try using `$facet` aggregation. One facet to count the matched documents and the other to group by job_id. This is somewhat clean way of doing, but there are other approaches.

Comment: can you share sample data

Comment: @prasad_ can you please write an example?

Comment: @varman I added sample data to the question. Thanks

Comment: are you using mongoTemplate?

Comment: @varman I am using what you see in the code, I don't get your question.

Comment: @varman Is it possible to count the $match before grouping using Mongo Template?

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/n3_1yE1Uktn does that help you, so I can convert to java

Comment: After that we can do the grouping again, let me know if it helps you

Comment: @varman, yes but imagine that one country is Italy and i wanna groupby job_id:                               [
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    baseurl: "yahoo.com",
    url: "abc.com",
    country: "us",
    job_id: "2020-07-18T09:43:55.000+00:00"
  },
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    baseurl: "yahoo.com",
    url: "xyz.com",
    country: "us",
    job_id: "2020-09-22T07:36:11.173+00:00"
  },
  {
    "user_id": 2,
    baseurl: "no need.com",
    url: "no need.com",
    country: "Italy",
    job_id: "2020-09-22T07:"
  },] so if input is "country=us" it should give me count match=2

Comment: @varman https://mongoplayground.net/p/SgEeyuJ9fbw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222073/discussion-between-parvaneh-parvin-and-varman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to autowire

```
@Autowired
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

Then the converted mongo script in java

```
public List<Object> test(){
    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        
        match(Criteria.where("country").is("us")),
        group(null)
            .push("$$ROOT").as("data")
            .count().as("count")
        

    ).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());

    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(YOUR_COLLECTION.class), Object.class).getMappedResults();
}
```

I haven't tested it, but hope, this should work.

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9uZ1vdn2rzU)**